# Troubleshooting delete[] (corrupted unsorted chunks)

Tags: c++, debugging, crash, free

My class `IOBuffer` manages a memory buffer. It has a method `grow()` that grows the underlying buffer.

```
template<class T>
class IOBuffer
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T * pointer_type;
    typedef long size_type;

    IOBuffer(size_type size = 2048, const void * data = nullptr) 
    : data_(), eod_(), begin_(), end_()
    {
        grow(size);
        if (data)
        {
            memcpy(data_, data, size);
            push(size);
        }
    }
    IOBuffer(const IOBuffer & rhs)
    {
        size_type capacity = rhs.capacity();
        size_type size = rhs.size();
        data_ = new value_type[capacity];
        eod_ = data_ + capacity;
        begin_ = data_;
        end_ = data_ + size;
        memcpy(data_, rhs.begin_, size);
    }

    IOBuffer(IOBuffer && rhs)
    : data_(rhs.data_), eod_(rhs.eod_),
    begin_(rhs.begin_), end_(rhs.end_)
    {
        rhs.data_ = nullptr;
    }

    IOBuffer & operator =(const IOBuffer & rhs)
    {
        const size_type & sz = rhs.size();
        begin_ = data_;
        grow(sz);
        memcpy(begin_, rhs.begin_, sz);
        end_ = begin_ + sz;
        return *this;
    }

    IOBuffer & operator =(IOBuffer &&rhs)
    {
        std::swap(data_, rhs.data_);
        std::swap(eod_, rhs.eod_);
        std::swap(begin_, rhs.begin_);
        std::swap(end_, rhs.end_);
        return *this;
    }

    ~IOBuffer()
    {
        delete[] data_;
    }

    pointer_type data() const
    {
        return begin_;
    }

    template<typename U>
    const U * data_as() const
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<U*>(begin_);
    }

    size_type size() const
    {
        return end_ - begin_;
    }

    size_type capacity() const
    {
        return eod_ - data_;
    }

    pointer_type end() const
    {
        return end_;
    }

    size_type available() const
    {
        return eod_ - end_;
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        return end_ == begin_;
    }

    bool grow(size_type newSize)
    {
        if (capacity() < newSize)
        {
            const size_type end = size();
            pointer_type temp = new value_type[newSize];
            if (data_ && end)
            {
                memcpy(temp, begin_, end * sizeof(value_type));
            }
            delete[] data_;
            data_ = temp;
            eod_ = data_ + newSize;
            begin_ = data_;
            end_ = data_ + end;
            return true;
        }
        else if(data_ != begin_)
        {
            const size_type end = size();
            memmove(data_, begin_, end * sizeof(value_type));
            begin_ = data_;
            end_ = begin_ + end;
        }

        return false;
    }

    size_type push(size_type n)
    {
        if (n > 0)
            end_ += n;
        assert(end_ >= data_ && end_ <= eod_);
        return n;
    }

    size_type consume(size_type n)
    {
        if (n > 0)
        {
            n = std::min(n, size());
            begin_ += n;
            assert(begin_ >= data_ && begin_ <= eod_);
        }
        return n;
    }

    void clear()
    {
        begin_ = end_ = data_;
    }

private:
    pointer_type data_;
    pointer_type eod_;
    pointer_type begin_;
    pointer_type end_;
};
```

Strangely, once a day, this happens:

```
 *** glibc detected *** ./mdrelay: free(): corrupted unsorted chunks: 0x0000000001c48db0 ***
```

And leaves me a core dump. Debugging that dump (with debug symbols, I get this trace)

```
#0  0x0000003510832925 in raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#1  0x0000003510834105 in abort () at abort.c:92
#2  0x0000003510870837 in __libc_message (do_abort=2, 
fmt=0x3510958ac0 "*** glibc detected *** %s: %s: 0x%s ***\n")
at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/libc_fatal.c:198
#3  0x0000003510876166 in malloc_printerr (action=3, 
str=0x3510958e48 "free(): corrupted unsorted chunks", ptr=<value optimized out>)
at malloc.c:6336
#4  0x0000003510878ca3 in _int_free (av=0x3510b8fe80, p=0x1c48da0, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:4832
#5  0x000000000042c529 in IOBuffer<unsigned char>::grow (this=0x1c48d18, newSize=4096)
at IOBuffer.hpp:125
```

and line 125 is `delete[] data_` inside method grow. Still when I print out what data_ points to:

```
(gdb) p data_
$1 = (IOBuffer<unsigned char>::pointer_type) 0x1c495c0
```

which is the correct

I'm puzzled on how I called `delete[]` pointing to `0x1c495c0` and `_int_free()` received `0x1c48da0`. The difference between those pointers is 2080 and the difference between the original pointer and the crash address is 2064. Also, (couldn't find the details of operator new[]/delete[] used in CentOS's glibc 2.12-1.132.el6_5.1 and libstdc++ 4.7.3, not the stock one), but I found the 2064 appears in memory, right before the address pointed by data_. This would rule out pointer corruption.

```
(gdb) x/2dg data_ - 0x10
0x1c495b0:      2064    2064
(gdb) print (long)data_ - 0x1c48db0
$4 = 2064
(gdb) print (long)data_ - 0x1c48da0
$5 = 2080
```

Probably operator delete() got optimised during compilation (there are no stack frames) and I can't track what happened to the pointer between delete[] and  _int_free(). Any ideas on this matter?

EDIT: to add some context, this class, is just a way I thought of managing a buffer for functions like recv() or read() without copying. It has four pointers: data_, eod_ (begin and end of buffer space) and begin_ and end_ (begin and end of incoming data). When a function read() returns n bytes, end_ is advanced by this n. As consequence, size() is end_ - begin_, the size from last read()'s. As the buffer is processed, begin_ advances until it meets end_. If something is left in the buffer , because there wasn't enough space between end_ and eod_ (or begin_ meets end_), grow() is called to free for space for next read(). It can increase overall buffer size or just move the remaining of data to the beginning of the buffer space, when reached a limit.

Comment: I'd just use a vector<uint8_t> as your underlying type.

Comment: Why are you using `memcpy`/`memmove` in a C++ program?

Comment: How is `size()` implemented, and under what circumstances would `data_ != begin_` ?

Comment: what does the function size() do? (I can guess, but we should see it). I would advise against having two variables end, and end_, recipe for confusion. Can't see your issue yet ...

Comment: what evidence do you have that in memmove() has space to received the data. Implication is that somehow begin_ and end_ have been manipulated elsewhere or you would not need this code. I would go and look at that elsewhere.

Comment: @djna begin_ and end_ are contained in the data_ buffer.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I stumbled on this article: http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2011/08/09/do-we-need-std-buffer/
and the idea appeared as a way to avoid copying things.

Comment: My thesis: begin_ and end_ are **sypposed** to point within the data buffer. The kind of symptom you have is often the result of accidentally over-running a block of allocated memory. Hence I'm suggesting being suspicious of wherever you manipulate begin_ and end_, and you don't show that code here.

Comment: the actual data is written by an I/O function, like read() or recv(). The intended usage is to `buf.push(::read(buf.end(), buf.available())` and then to `consume(do_something(buf.data_as<SomeType>()))`. The class itself is bascally read-only, except for the (eventual) copy operations.

Comment: @user666412 That is just one side of the coin. It proposes as a solution to old compilers not supporting a modern C++ STL Library is to update the C++ STL library differently. And while not being "particularly convenient or efficient", vector<uint8_t> is also not particularly inconvenient or inefficient. To be quite honest you should only build a class like this for pedagogical reasons or if you measured that the (alleged) inefficiencies of vector<uint8_t> are too high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of the class in the post appears to be stable, thanks to thoughtful comments.

Previous versions of the class reported, in `available()`, a larger buffer than the actual allocated space and `recv()` caused the buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

From the scenario, I think you may write the data exceeded the range of data_ buffer in other place, you may need check the code out of this function.

On the other hand, when calling memcpy/memmove, are you sure end variable unit is bytes, do you need change it from end to end*sizeof(value_type)?

Comment: it seems so. Yet, the information pointed by data_ and before appear to be valid.I've added an assert in the method that adds data to the buffer data_ in order to make sure of that doesn't happen.
that's right, I'll mutiply by sizeof ... thanks for the tip.